# A riddly riddle

Tags: riddle, steganography, cryptic-clues

A meta riddle of sorts.
$\phantom{/Be/}$

> My prefix is a bamboozling.
>   My infix is tantilizing.
>   My suffix is full.
>   My whole is disdainful.

$\phantom{/of/}$

> Element partially responsible for destruction of an evil city (6)

$\phantom{/put on}$

> With two I'm silvery white.
>   With four I'm a cover for nostrils.
>   With all six I'm a food.

(5)

Comment: I like how you fit a cryptic-Riley-Tyo into one puzzle ^-^

Comment: Certain ones @QuantumTwinkie.

Comment: Are you *sure* that the [cryptic-clues] tag is correct here? Cryptic clues follow a strict set of rules.

Comment: @Deusovi yes, there is a cryptic clue in this.

Comment: Oh no, what have you done! You can't combine all three, it's too powerful!

Comment: @Riley, well seeing as the mods are still kidnapped, I was trying to channel the power of riddles to break them free

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First:

My prefix is a bamboozling.

> A **con** is a bamboozling.

My infix is tantilizing.

> To **tempt** is to tantalize.

My suffix is full.

> **ous** is a suffix from Latin for full.

My whole is disdainful.

> **Contemptuous** means disdainful.

Second:

Element partially responsible for destruction of an evil city (6)

> Credit to ferret for **sulfur**, which destroyed Sodom and Gomorrah.

Third:

With two I'm silvery white.

> **Ce** is the symbol for Cesium, which is silvery-white (according to some sources).

With four I'm a cover for nostrils.

> A **cere** covers bird nostrils.

With all six I'm a food.

> **Cereal** is a food.

Finally:

> There is hidden text before each puzzle, which combined with the answers yields the cryptic clue "Be contemptuous of sulfur put on cereal (5)." The answer is **scorn**, which means "be contemptuous", and scorn = s + corn where s = sulfur and corn = cereal.

Comment: I was stuck on part three, thinking `gi` for a judo jacket, which is usually white, and `gill` for a cover for nostrils. Nice job!

Comment: Thanks! I actually backsolved the third puzzle using the meta.

Comment: I had tried that but missed the hidden text. I was thinking "contemptful sulfur lizard/breather"... would be something related to "Dragonrage" lol

Comment: @ferret i shall have to keep that in mind for a new puzzle. :thinkingface:

Answer (score 6):

Partial answers:

> **contemptful**
>  A **con** bamboozles somebody
>  When you are **tempt**ed you are tantalized
>  Suffix is literally **ful**

Part 2

> **sulfur**, archaically known as **brimstone**, which destroyed the evil cities of Sodom and Gomorrah